# How to remove a list of values from a 2D list in python efficiently?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity, list-comprehension

Let's say that we have this array:

```
people = [[Amy, 25], [Bella, 30], [Charlie, 29], [Dean, 21], [Elliot, 19]]
```

And I have a list of names that I want to remove from it:

```
people_rem = [Amy, Charlie, Dean]
```

So that our final array will look like this:

```
final_people = [[Bella, 30], [Elliot, 19]]
```

I have tried doing this using list comprehension, which works, but it's incredibly slow (not in this specific case, but in my real life usage i have a lot of lists with a lot more items):

```
final_people = [person for person in people if people[0] not in people_rem]
```

How would I do this in a way that's efficient and fast?

Comment: `people_rem` should be a `set` not a `list`, or else each lookup will be linear time instead of constant time. So just use `people_rem = set(people_rem)` **outside the loop** and then the overall code should be linear time on the size of `people`, not polynomial time, O(M*N) on the size of people *and* people_rem

Comment: Oh that's it! I tried that before but I turned the list into a set inside the loop. Can't believe it was so simple. Thank you!!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Deletion will still be linear time though because you're using a list. You want the thing you are deleting from to be the hash table.

Comment: @MadPhysicist they aren't actually deleting, though, but yes, if they were, that would be 1) fraught with errors 2) inefficient

Comment: @Bobobot yes, if you re-create the set inside the loop, that obviates the advantage, since it is a linear cost to create the set, so you are back to O(M*N)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a data structure that supports only linear lookup. You can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module to do logarithmic-time lookup (deletion will still be linear time), but why bother when there is a structure that lets you do constant-time lookup and deletion?

Use a dictionary:

```
people = dict(people)
```

Now removal is trivial:

```
for name in people_rem:
    del people[name]
```

Notice that this runs in `O(len(people_rem))` time, not `O(len(people))`. Since presumably `len(people_rem) < len(people_rem)`, this is a good thing (TM). I'm not counting the `O(len(people))` conversion to a dictionary, since you can likely do that directly when you create `people` in the first place, making it no more expensive than building the initial list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it through pandas? Check if this is faster.

```
import pandas as pd

people = [['Amy', 25], ['Bella', 30], ['Charlie', 29], ['Dean', 21], ['Elliot', 19]]

people_rem = ['Amy', 'Charlie', 'Dean']

def remove(people, people_rem):
    df = pd.DataFrame(people, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
    for person in people_rem:
        df.drop(df[df.Name == person].index, inplace=True)
    return df.values.tolist()

final_people = remove(people, people_rem)
print(final_people)
```

Comment: Almost certainly it will not be. This is similarly polynomial time, with worse constant factors

Comment: However, using a bulk-selection process could potentially be, so something like `~df['Name'].isin(people_rem)` to select the dataframe. Although pandas is hugely overkill for this sort of problem